# Does anybody recognize the biplane used here?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Little red biplane used here in WKRP In Cincinnati S3E01.  I don’t recognize the type and I’ve never seen this aircraft before. Of interest appears to have trailing link main landing gear.  Anybody know what type of airplane this is?

Comment: I wonder if there's any chance that it's a "crosswind" gear set-up?

Comment: The type of airplane is in the description of the video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was N14041 which was a Waco UMF owned and flown by Harold Johnson.

[Aerial Visuals N14041](https://aerialvisuals.ca/AirframeDossier.php?Serial=49521)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Waco umf3 the flying mayor of Moraine Ohio, Harold Johnson and it now sits in the Waco museum in Troy Ohio. I grew up flying with Harold his hanger and my father's were connected back to back with a door between them. That's Darrell's (my father) 450 stearman in the background of the 2nd picture.

Comment: Hi Brian, and welcome to Aviation.SE.  That's very cool that you have the personal connection to that aircraft from younger days!  Thanks for adding the additional info on the aircraft's current location - no doubt it's a beautiful part of their collection.

Comment: Great info, but it should really be a comment on the other answer. Once you have enough rep, you'll be able to comment on anyone's question or answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/63540)